# Java create event between unrelated classes

Tags: java, events

Hello I would like to know about the simplest (or less twisted) way to create an event linking two unrelated classes.

Let's say I have the following scheme:  (a -> b means a contains b)

```
class ZeroThing extends JPanel container1 
  -> class FirstThing extends JPanel container1.1
    -> JProgressBar bar
    -> JButton but
  -> class SecondThing extends JPanel container1.2
    -> JLabel lab1
    -> JLabel lab2
```

I would like a letter to be automatically added to lab2 every time the button but is pressed.
What is the simplest way to link but's event to lab2?

EDIT: What I would like to do:

```
but.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    lab2.setText("Hello");  
    }
});
```

This cannot work because but is a JButton contained in the FirstThing class, whereas lab2 is a JLabel contained in the SecondThing class. How can I bypass this situation?

Comment: The simplest (not the best) way is to pass an instance of `Class1` to the `ActionListener()` in `Class2`.  Then inside `ActionListener` you can use a `set...` method to update the label. This will create a rather tightly coupled configuration.

Comment: At which point should the classe1 instance be passed to the class2's actionListener? According to my schema, but has no way to access lab2 :S

Comment: You will need to clarify your question. What are the "*unrelated classes*" in your case?  Does *unrelated* mean *from different packages*?

Comment: Ok I edited my post. I forgot to mention that the JButton is part of a first class, and my label is part of a second one. Basically none of them has access to the other..

Comment: Still not clear. Are `FirstThing` and `SecondThing` **inner classes** of `ZeroThing`?

Comment: Yes they are! ZeroThing is composed of FirstThing and SecondThing. SecondThing is composed of lab1 and lab2. IS it ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you asked about *simplest* way, here is the one that implements tight coupling between classes and, therefore, is plain ugly:

1. In `FirstThing` create a public method `SetLab2Text(...)`.
2. In `SecondThing` create a class variable to hold a reference to an instance of `FirstThing`: `FirstThing ft = new FirstThing();` It assumes that `FirstThing`'s default constructor just initializes class variables and does not implement any GUI stuff.
3. In your `ActionListener` for `but` add `ft.SetLab2Text("Hello");`

Again, this is just a quick and dirty way to accomplish your task and does **not** represent a good design.

Comment: Thank you PM. It appears to be a dirty way indeed compared to the MVC design, however this will not be an issue for my project is quite small and tidy :)

Answer (score 0):

You should think about a Model-View-Controller (MVC) design here.

In this case, your Label is a View, your Button is a Controller, and you have not yet defined a Model - but you should.

The Model contains the data you want to change. When the Button is pressed, it calls some `set` method on the model (or even something like `addLetter()`)

When the model receives a data change, it should fire events to all of the views that are listening to the model. Which means the model also needs `addModelListener()` and `removeModelListener()` and a `fireLetterAdded(String letter)` method that calls a method, like `letterAdded(String letter)`, on all `LetterListener`s that have been added to the model.

Which, of course, means you'll need to create a `LetterListener` interface that has a `letterAdded(String letter)` method, and your second class implements `LetterListener` and adds itself to the Model.

That's a really quick overview of implementing MVC, and I've glossed over a bunch of stuff. But is it enough to get started?

Comment: Thanks David. That's not enough for a beginner like me to implement it, but that was the information I needed! I am reading a tutorial on MVC design right now :)